# convert list<int> to list<long>

Tags: c#, generics, list

How to convert `List<int>` to `List<long>` in C#?

Comment: Repost/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296055/convert-listint-to-listlong-asp-net

Answer (score 33):

Like this:

```
List<long> longs = ints.ConvertAll(i => (long)i);
```

This uses C# 3.0 lambda expressions; if you're using C# 2.0 in VS 2005, you'll need to write

```
List<long> longs = ints.ConvertAll<int, long>(
    delegate(int i) { return (long)i; }
);
```

Comment: Works flawlessly!

Answer (score 19):

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
List<long> longs = ints.Select(i => (long)i).ToList();
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var longs = ints.Cast<long>().ToList();
```

Comment: i have InvalidCastExpression