# convert List<int> to List<long> asp.net

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert list<int> to list<long>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295957/convert-listint-to-listlong)

How to convert `List<int>` to `List<long>` in asp.net c#....